# Question about using Terraform deploying to Azure

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Is there a way to pass the URN of an Azure image to `storage_image_reference` instead of using Publisher, Offer, and SKU separately?

For example. passing this

```
OpenLogic:CentOS:7.5:latest
```

instead of

```
storage_image_reference {
  publisher = "OpenLogic"
  offer     = "CentOS"
  sku       = "7.5"
  version   = "latest"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming terraform 0.11

```
variable "urn" {
  type = "list"
}

urn = split(":", "OpenLogic:CentOS:7.5:latest")

...

storage_image_reference {
  publisher = "${urn[0]}"
  offer     = "${urn[1]}"
  sku       = "${urn[2]}"
  version   = "${urn[3]}"
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to provide multiple Linux flavors with just the one variable?

Comment: you could use a list of strings, then perform the `split` within the `storage_image_reference` using `count` to rotate through?

Comment: yeah that might work.  With the addition of more conditionals, it seems like .12 might be the way to go.